# Cannot print "no"?

Tags: if-statement, printing, lua, expression

I am very,VERY new to Lua so I got a little stuck studying it.

Why is it that I cannot print "no" here? What else should I add?

```
if (expression_1) then
    if (expression_2) then
      print("yes")
    end
  else
  if (expression_3) then
      print("no")
    end 
  end
```

Comment: This is not valid Lua code: you need to add `end` at the bottom.

Comment: Okay but it still doesn't work. Do "expression_1" and "expression_2" have to be true in order to print "no"?

Comment: You need to give more detail. Probably with actual code.

Answer (score 2):

`expression_1` must not be `true` (`nil` or `false`) and `expression_3` must be `true` in order to print "no".

If this is your entire code, "no" is not printed because `expression_3` is `nil` as you did not assign any value yet.

The following code will print no:

```
local expression_3 = true    
if (expression_1) then
  if (expression_2) then
    print("yes")
  end
else
  if (expression_3) then
    print("no")
  end 
end
```

You could also write

```
local expression_3 = true    
if expression_1 and expression_2 then
  print("yes")
elseif expression_3 then
  print("no")
end
```

btw and you do not need parenthesis for the if-statement.